# My website which is on http redirects on https when i am visiting any page of http website

Tags: http, ssl, cpanel, shared-hosting, whm

my one website is on https and all other websites on non-https means http if i visit any pages of http website with https it is redirect to https website 
i am using WHM version 11.50.6 and Server OS is CentOS 6.8

Comment: what's your question? edit/explain your problem clearly!

Comment: i have only one website https://abcdotcom website and i have many websites which is on http. When i am using any page of https://xyzdotcom/pages.html and if pages.html exist in https://abcdotcom website then it is redirect to https://abcdotcom/pahes.html

Comment: do you want to redirect all the incoming requests from `http://site1.com` to `https://site2.com`?

Comment: Suppose I have 3 websites(though I have 500) on my server abcdotcom, xyzdotcom and pqrdotcom. All pointing to same server IP. Installed the SSL on  domain xyzdotcom which is working fine. now any request made on https of abcdotcom and pqrdotcom automatically takes you to the files hosted on the https of xyzdotcom which I believe is how it would work. Now if we have any file say xyzdotcom/test.html, it is accessible on https of other two websites as well which even google is able to index. Need some solution through htaccess or virtualhost settings so that https works for xyzdotcom only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .*  https://domainname.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainname\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS is set by rewrite rules specified in your htaccess file/server settings. I believe what would have happened in your case is, the rewrite rule has been set to match any URL.

> Any URL redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abcd.com/$1 [R,L]
```

> Specific domain redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abcd.com/$1 [R,L]
```

> Specific folder redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abcd.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

If you want to deny access while accessing from other domains use `order allow,deny`

Comment: The issue I am having with https traffic only. If it is http then the request is already going to the respective domain. All https is going to xyzdotcom. How can I handle the traffic being called from URL https abcdotcom/test.html ?

Comment: If that's the case, then use rewrite rules to redirect https pages to http for the domains you need

Comment: i added a answer post which is working for me. And thanks @kowsikbabu for helping me